# How to put Viewpager with recyclerview in BottomSheet?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have a bottom sheet in which I want to show viewpager with tablayout and in each fragment in viewpager I have list (recyclerview). But Bottomsheet behave unexpectedly. Any Idea, How to do it very helpful for me.

Comment: please put some code man!

Comment: What is main problem? RecyclerView not working?